# How to send email on users behalf using AWS SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I can see that from SendGrid I can send email, where the from field will show any email which the end user will put. With AWS SES how can I achieve this?

As I see in the docs it needs to verify the email/domain before doing this. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, not from SES. You can setup your own SMTP server to do so, but the emails might (and most probably) end up in spambox of the receiver.

Comment: @hjpotter92 do you know how sendgrid is able to do this? There is something like verify email, so If I can get access maybe then I can use it?

Answer (score 0):

In SES you can only send emails from verified domains or verified emails. And in either cases you would need to own them otherwise you cannot verify them and subsequently you cannot use those.

Once you verify a domain it is more liberal in the sense that now you can use any arbitrary id at that domain
So e.g. if you verify xyz.com domain then you can use any id  @xyz.com
E.g. myid1@xyz.com or jghdgd@xyz.com

Comment: Ya this is not good, but I saw sendgrid allows us to send email from any address?

Is it just about policy?

Answer (score 0):

That might be about policy
Not very familiar with send grid.
We use sparkpost as another ESP and there as well you can only use only authenticated domains. And that makes sense as well because otherwise people can just adopt any arbitrary identity for spamming